# How can I apply cpu and memory limit to "Web Content"?

Tags: cpulimit

I tried to put memory limit on programs, by using their desktop shortcuts in order to apply the same limit for their child process too.

I found that "Web Content" is a separate process in [what is web content](https://superuser.com/questions/1299746/whats-web-content-in-top-doing-taking-up-memory) and it uses high memory not only in my computer.

I am using for instance for Firefox and child processes in Firefox's `.desktop` shortcut having an execution line:

```
Exec=sh -c "ulimit -m 131072;nice -u username 19; cpulimit -l 25 -- ../firefox/firefox/firefox"
```

Although sometimes, Firefox uses a little bit higher than 25(i.e 26,27) but it seemed that it worked. Also GeckoMain is limited in terms of cpu.

However, I noticed that process named "Web Content" continues to use much higher CPU when Firefox is open. How can I apply cpu and memory limit to "Web Content"?

Answer (score 0):

"Web Content" is a subprocess of FireFox.  If you run `pgrep -a "Web Content"` it will list all of these processes.  The penultimate field will be the process ID of the parent FireFox, for example:

```
4940 /usr/lib64/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 1 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 38 -prefMapSize 289537 -jsInit 285716 -parentBuildID 20220214091044 -appdir /usr/lib64/firefox/browser 4376 tab
```

where 4376 is the parent ID.